# angular-upload not populating model when used with angular-formly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

options.data.fieldToMatch

Hello everyone, please bear with me as this is my first post on StackOverflow. I've been an anonymous user for years and have always found the answers to my questions by searching. This one, however, perplexes me a bit.

I'm having an issue integrating angular-upload with angular-formly using angular 1.4. The form model is not getting updated when a file is selected.

I have a code example on jsbin at http://jsbin.com/cozanowure/edit?js, and the same code on plunkr at http://plnkr.co/edit/aDi8breDPFFGrNdzh2i4?p=preview

Below is the same code on the 2 above provided links:

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular
    .module('app', ['lr.upload', 'formly', 'formlyBootstrap']);

  app.run(['formlyConfig', function(formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
      name: 'licensefile',
      extends: 'input',
      defaultOptions: {
        ngModelAttrs: {
          multiple: {
            bound: 'ng-multiple',
            attribute: 'multiple'
          },
          accept: {
            bound: 'ng-accept',
            attribute: 'accept'
          }
        },
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'License File',
          type: 'file',
          required: true,
          multiple: false,
          accept: '*.lic'
        },
        validation: {
          messages: {
            required: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
              //return scope.to.label + ' is required '
              return 'Please select a license file';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });

    formlyConfig.setType({
      name: 'email',
      extends: 'input',
      defaultOptions: {
        templateOptions: {
          type: 'email',
          label: 'Email Address',
          placeholder: 'email address',
          pattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)',
          message: '$viewValue + " is not a valid email address"'
        },
        validation: {
          messages: {
            required: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
              return 'Please enter an email address';
            },
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }]);

  app.controller('AppController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.model = {};
    vm.fields = [{
      type: 'licensefile',
      key: 'lfile',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'License File',
        focus: true,
      }
    }, {
      type: 'input',
      key: 'someTextField',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Some Text'
      }
    }];
  });
}());
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/leon/angular-upload/master/angular-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/kentcdodds/apiCheck.js/master/dist/api-check.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/formly-js/angular-formly/master/dist/formly.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/master/dist/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AppController as vm">
    <pre>{{vm.model | json}}</pre>
    <form name="fileForm" >
      <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" ></formly-form>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any help and guidance in why the model isn't getting updated with the selected files would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: Have you had any progress with his?

Comment: angular-upload does not utilise `ng-model`